# c++ class member function pointer does not work rightly in class

Tags: c++

The member function pointer of objects are different, but they run on the same member function.
Code as follows:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A *child = NULL;
    void (A::*_backwardFunc)() = NULL;
    void FuncA()
    {
        cout << "This is function A." << endl;
    }

    void FuncB()
    {
        cout << "This is function B." << endl;
    }

    void set(int token = 0)
    {
        this->_backwardFunc = (token == 0) ? &A::FuncA : &A::FuncB;
    }

    void print()
    {
        if (_backwardFunc) {
            (this->*_backwardFunc)();
        }
        if (child && child->_backwardFunc) {
            (child->*_backwardFunc)();
        }
    }
};
 
int main()
{
    A a, b;
    a.set(0);
    b.set(1);
    a.child = &b;
    a.print();
    b.print();
}
```

Expection:

This is function A.

This is function B.

This is function B.

But I got:

This is function A.

This is function A.

This is function B.

Anyone knows？ Many Thx.

Comment: Why do you expect that? You select function A for object a, don't you?

Comment: You can step through this using a debugger. That is likely to thoroughly explain the behavior.

Comment: Tested on Linux: g++ (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5).

Comment: @Igor R.   Right. obj a set function A,  obj b set function B.  and a's child is b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `a.print();`, in `print()`, `(child->*_backwardFunc)();` is calling `a._backwardFunc` (on `child`), it points to `A::FuncA` . If you want to call `child->_backwardFunc` (which points to `A::FuncB`), it should be

```
(child->*(child->_backwardFunc))();
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xI76D37VuwLf5U2h)

Comment: It sounds like "(child->*_backwardFunc)();" worked as "(this->*_backwardFunc)();"  Why "child->" is not ok?  
I found "(this->*(child->_backwardFunc))();"  is also valid.

Comment: @kaiyuanxie `(this->*_backwardFunc)();` is calling `_backwardFunc` on `this`, it's not same as `(child->*_backwardFunc)();`, which is calling `_backwardFunc` on `child`. It depends on your intent, you want to call ***which*** member function pointer on ***which*** object?

Comment: The purpose is each object has its own member function pointer pointed to different member functions and can be invoked in a certain object. eg. Class_obj_a's ptr pointed Class_FuncA  and Class_obj_b's ptr pointed Class_FuncB. The `Class_obj_b->*ptr` should run Class_FuncB wherever be inside or outside the Class. In this case, however, '->' of `(child->*_backwardFunc)();`  confused me.